# rowSums() error: 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, csv, types, sum

I am trying to sum each row of the incomeData table. Here's my data:
[image]

Here's my code

```
incomeData <- read.csv("~/xxxx/xxxx/IncomeData279332c31ddd.csv", 
header=FALSE)
incomeData <- incomeData[-1,] #remove the first row in the incomeData
incomeData$district_sampleSum <- rowSums(incomeData)
sapply(incomeData, typeof)
```

I kept getting an error from this line:

```
> incomeData$district_sampleSum <- rowSums(incomeData)
Error in rowSums(incomeData) : 'x' must be numeric
```

I tried to debug by trying:

```
sapply(incomeData, typeof)
```

It shows all columns are integers and doubles. So I am not sure why R would complain x to be numeric.

[image]

Comment: `typeof` is misleading you. Use `class` instead. `typeof` will return integer for factors.

Comment: Set `header=TRUE` and drop that second line. By reading the colnames as data you are forcing everything to factor.

Comment: It worked and thank you!